# Is this prob on weighted bipartite graph solvable in polynomial time or it is NP-Complete

Tags: algorithm, graph, complexity-theory, np-complete, bipartite

I encounter this problem recently and I want to know whether it is NP-Complete or solvable in polynomial time:

Given a weighted bipartite graph G=(V,E) where V can be partitioned into two sets A and B and E is a set of edges connecting A and B. The weight of an edge (v,u) is denoted as w(v,u).

Do the following sequentially:

1. Pick a node v∈A,
2. remove all node u∈B for every (v,u)∈E and,
3. add the weight w(v,u) to the total score for every edges deleted.

The goal is to find the sequence of nodes v1,…,vn∈A that maximizes the total score.

I have searched for the bank of NP-Complete problems to find something possible can reduce to this problem but I haven't found anything useful yet. Any suggestions would be extremely helpful!

Comment: Are you sure the total score is not a constant?

Comment: Perhaps instead of choosing nodes you are limited to choosing _edges_?  And then perhaps removing its nodes and all edges on them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's an NP-hardness reduction from feedback arc set. I'm debating whether to post it.

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy The removal of nodes in B also removes edges not incident to the chosen node v.

Comment: Yes. By removing a node I mean also removing the edges that connect to the node

Comment: @DavidEisenstat. That's a good point. I haven't considered that yet actually. Let me also think about it

Comment: @phs Basically every time I need to pick a node, then remove all the edges connected to it. Then the weights on those edges are added to the total score

Comment: @user9836: are you adding ALL the deleted edges to total score, or only the ones that connect u and v?

Comment: @andreiKucharavy: Every time I choose v, ALL edges connected to v are deleted. And ALL edges are added to total score.

Comment: In this case the total weight is well a constant, as long as you can use all the nodes. Otherwise, for a fixed n, this problem is reducible to a matroid and thus is #A log #A complex at worst.